# c++ std::atomic concurrency printing

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, atomic, stdatomic

Hello everyone I have a code for threads to print their number and number that they are counting:

```
void print_num_n_times(std::uintmax_t thread_num, std::uintmax_t num_times_to_print = 100)
{
    static std::atomic_bool is_printing{ false };
    std::uintmax_t i = 0;
    while (i < num_times_to_print)
    {
        //if the thread is not acquired.
        while (is_printing.load());
        //if the thread previous value was false (maybe another thread was intterupting.
        if (!is_printing.exchange(true)) {
            std::cout << "Output from thread " << thread_num << " Value: " << i + 1 << '\n';
            is_printing.exchange(false);
            i++;
        }
    }
}
```

and this is the only solution I have found for multiple threads to print nicely like this (2 threads count to 5):

```
Output from thread 2 Value: 1
Output from thread 2 Value: 2
Output from thread 2 Value: 3
Output from thread 2 Value: 4
Output from thread 2 Value: 5
Output from thread 1 Value: 1
Output from thread 1 Value: 2
Output from thread 1 Value: 3
Output from thread 1 Value: 4
Output from thread 1 Value: 5
```

Is there a better solution, because it's slow and I feel like there could be a better solution.
Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Is there any reason why you didn't use `std::mutex`? I fail to see what benefit you have from implementing a spinlock here

Comment: Busy loops are not a great way to coordinate different threads.  You should look into [`std::mutex`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/mutex) and maybe [conditional variables](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread#:~:text=A%20condition%20variable%20is%20a,always%20associated%20with%20a%20mutex) instead.  But if you really want any meaningful help, you need to provide more context, so please add a [mre] to your question showing how these threads are actually used.

Comment: I second @PaulSanders for the conditional variables. They look like a right fit (you can wait in other threads without "busy wait", and notify them when you are finished with the correct thread)

Comment: @stribor14 Yes, I agree.  In many 'real life' situations you only want [one of] your 'worker threads' to wake up when there is something for it to do.

Comment: I know about `std::mutex`, but it's was a part of an assignment where I had to use `std::atomic`.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a simplistic version of your code using a [`std::mutex`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/mutex) and [`std::lock_guard`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/lock_guard)s to demonstrate one-shot threads with no other synchronization than using said mutex. In real situations you'd often use a [`std::condition_variable`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/condition_variable) and a [`std::unique_lock`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/unique_lock) to signal longer running threads that it's time to do some work.

```cpp
#include <cstdint>
#include <iostream>
#include <mutex>
#include <thread>
#include <vector>

void print_num_n_times(std::mutex& mtx, std::uintmax_t thread_num,
                       std::uintmax_t num_times_to_print)
{
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(mtx); // wait here until acquiring the mutex lock

    // this section will only be run by one thread (having locked the mutex) at a time
    for (decltype(num_times_to_print) i = 0; i < num_times_to_print; ++i) {
        std::cout << "Output from thread " << thread_num << " Value: " << i + 1 << '\n';
    }
} // when `lock` goes out of scope, the mutex lock is released

// An auto joining thread for C++11, in C++20, use std::jthread
struct jthread : std::thread {
    using std::thread::operator=;
    ~jthread() { if(joinable()) join(); }
};

int main() {
    std::mutex mtx;                   // a mutex to use by all threads
    std::vector<jthread> threads(3);  // create 3 jthreads to run `print_num_n_times`

    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(mtx); // lock while starting all threads

    // start the threads (while locking the mutex)
    for (size_t i = 0; i < threads.size(); ++i) {
        threads[i] = std::thread(print_num_n_times, std::ref(mtx), i + 1, 5);
    }
} // 1. the lock_guard goes out of scope - the mutex is released
  // 2. threads start acquiring the mutex lock (in an indeterminate order) 
  //    and
  // 2. the vector goes out of scope and its destructor is called
  // 3. the jthreads in the vector all join()s their threads in their destructors
  // 4. finally the mutex is destroyed
```

Possible output:

```
Output from thread 3 Value: 1
Output from thread 3 Value: 2
Output from thread 3 Value: 3
Output from thread 3 Value: 4
Output from thread 3 Value: 5
Output from thread 1 Value: 1
Output from thread 1 Value: 2
Output from thread 1 Value: 3
Output from thread 1 Value: 4
Output from thread 1 Value: 5
Output from thread 2 Value: 1
Output from thread 2 Value: 2
Output from thread 2 Value: 3
Output from thread 2 Value: 4
Output from thread 2 Value: 5
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. The problem is that it's was a part of an assignment where I had to use `std::atomic`.

Comment: @AvihaiShalom You're welcome! I see, but does using `std::atomic` exclude using `mutex`es etc.? You could use the `atomic` to signal other things, like ending the threads (instead of having the loop end after a number of iterations) etc.

Comment: and how do I do that?

Comment: @AvihaiShalom You could use an atomic in a loop condition for example.